# What is the purpose of Ruby's unknown class?

Tags: ruby, class, documentation

I was looking through the Ruby Core API and noticed "unknown" at the bottom of the *Classes* list. When you go to that class's page at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/unknown.html, you will notice that there is no content.

What is the purpose of this class, i.e. when and how would you use it? If there is no purpose, why is it documented on ruby-doc.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is some kind of artifact of the documentation system and not an actual class in Ruby.

The documentation is produced by parsing the Ruby source code and can often get a little confused about what it's seeing. There's ways of coaching it with additional comments to ignore things it shouldn't document and so on, but tracking down which particular file or line produced this "unknown" reference is not necessarily easy.

You may want to report this as a bug in the documentation. That page isn't helpful, and is more confusing than anything.

Comment: You can make an educated guess though. The documentation mentions `time.c` so it's most likely this [line](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_1/time.c#L5292). rdoc sees a class definition but no string literal (like basically everywhere else) but it fallbacks to `unknown` for better or for worse. It also belongs to a new 2.6 feature and the `unknown` class doesn't appear in the docs of previous versions.

Comment: Super interesting! The `unknown` doesn't even show on the Ruby 2.5.x or 2.4.x versions. Keep going back and the file mentioned changes to `io.c` in 2.2.x and 2.3.x, and then to `process.c` in 2.1.x, 2.0.0 and the 1.9 series. Landing back in 1.8.x it mentions `prec.c`.

Comment: BTW, the docs at https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/ don't have an entry for "unknown"

Comment: @Stefan: docs.ruby-lang.org (official) is using the latest RDoc version. Maybe ruby-doc.org (inofficial) is using an older one. The 2.6 `NEWS` file even mentions RDoc parsing fixes.

Comment: There's a couple issues that already mention **unknown.html**: a closed one about [ignoring dynamically added methods](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/pull/661), and an open one from 2013 about [C parsing valid files](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/issues/218). Given this info, should a new issue be opened?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `unknown` class in Ruby.  To prove @tadman's point simply run an IRB console:

```
irb(main):006:0> NilClass
=> NilClass
irb(main):007:0> Object
=> Object
irb(main):008:0> ZeroDivisionError
=> ZeroDivisionError
irb(main):009:0> Unknown
NameError: uninitialized constant Unknown
irb(main):010:0> unknown
NameError: undefined local variable or method `unknown' for main:Object
```

Comment: Well, there's [`fatal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/fatal.html) which is not capitalized and is definitely a thing unlike `unknown`.

Comment: Capitalization is just a rule for constant. It is possible to assign a class to a method or a local variable with non-capitalized name.

Comment: It does not make sense to check the capitalized `Unknown`, which appears nowhere. It still makes sense that you checked the non-capitalized `unknown`.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: The code shows that there's no constant `Unknown` and no method or variable `unknown`. There could still be an `unknown` class which just wasn't assigned to a constant, just like the `fatal` class.